# How to populate an array with channels in go

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to build an array with go channels. I do not care about insertion order however I only receive the last item from the channel.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func AddToMap(thing string, val string, c chan map[string]string) {
    mappy := make(map[string]string)
    mappy[thing] = val
    c <- mappy
}

func main() {
    item := make([]map[string]string, 0, 10)
    list1 := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "blah", "barf"}
    list2 := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
    c := make(chan map[string]string)
    for index, val := range list1 {
    go AddToMap(val, list2[index], c)
}
    ret := <-c
    item = append(item, ret)
    fmt.Println(item)
}
```

My output is: [map[barf:five]]

Comment: you only receive from the channel once, so...

Comment: #facepalm Thanks hobbs!

Answer (score 3):

You need to read *continuously* from channel, as data is being written into it. And when you're done pumping data into channel, close it. Here is how it can work.

Note: AddToMap is not being called as independent goroutine. It can be done using waitgroup, because we need to know when we need to close channel *c*, which will be after all *AddToMap* have been run.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func AddToMap(thing string, val string, c chan map[string]string) {
    mappy := make(map[string]string)
    mappy[thing] = val
    c <- mappy
}

func main() {
    item := make([]map[string]string, 0, 10)
    list1 := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "blah", "barf"}
    list2 := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
    c := make(chan map[string]string)
    go func(){
        for index, val := range list1 {
            AddToMap(val, list2[index], c)
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    for ret := range c {
        item = append(item, ret)
    }
    fmt.Println(item)
}
```